# Team Foundation Server 2013 Release Management Scheduled Deployments

Tags: ms-release-management

With TFS2013's new Release Management, is it possible to deploy at a given date/time, as in scheduled releases.

For minimized impact on users in Production, we'd like to be able to deploy during down time (during the night for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

When approving the acceptance step (first step of a stage), in the popup, you will have the option to approve now, or give a date and time. If you select a date/time, the deployment will be triggered only then.

No need to wake up in the middle of the night!

Comment: That means you have to manually select a date/time. If you want to schedule a release every night there is no automated solution.

Comment: @ds19 In this case, simply schedule a build every night. Set up that build will trigger the release automatically.